# IIS error when trying to debug new asp.net app using chrome

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I created a new asp.net mvc application.  When I try to run the project on localhost, using (IIS Express (Google Chrome)), chrome gives me the following error:

This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

If I change the browser to debug using Internet Explorer it runs without issue.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: There could be many reasons. https://www.google.com/search?q=err_ssl_protocol_error&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.191j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 In general though you don't need to bother with HTTPs and SSL when you're testing locally, and it can be a pain to validate certificates etc for localhost. Simplest thing might just be to use plain HTTP instead. Worry about HTTPS when you deploy it to a server.

Comment: Sounds like a Chrome setting to use SSL.

Comment: same here, no solutions found

Comment: See below.  Cleared SSL State and it fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  Because it was happening only to newly created solutions and not previous solutions and that I had ran a Visual Studio update that day I thought it was something weird going in related to that.  In the end I just had to clear the SSL State in Internet Properties and it was fine after that.